# Pgfplots: How do I change plot line width independently of axis line width?

Tags: pgfplots

I can use something like `\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={line width=1pt}}` to make all lines `1pt` thick, but I would like to make only the plot lines thicker.
I can do this on a per-plot-basis with `\addplot [thick] ...`, but how can I set it for all plots?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found this non-obvious to find out, but there is a `plot` "type" or whatever the name is, which means, this will work:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every plot/.append style={very thick}]
```

Or

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every axis plot/.append style={very thick}]
```

Or

```
\pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style={very thick}}
```

Make sure to also use "every axis plot" in the \pgfplotsset in order to work properly.